# Transactional evolutions in Play

Tags: postgresql, transactions, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-evolutions

Is it possible to make evolutions transactional, so each evolution succeeds or fails
altogether?

I've tried to wrap the ups and downs with begin/commit block (I use PostgreSQL), but received a strange error:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot change transaction read-only property in the middle of a transaction.
  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.setReadOnly(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:725)
  at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.setReadOnly(ConnectionHandle.java:1324)
  at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.<init>(ConnectionHandle.java:262)
  at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.recreateConnectionHandle(ConnectionHandle.java:281)
  at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.close(ConnectionHandle.java:512)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.applyScript(Evolutions.scala:274)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:472)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:502)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:461)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:459)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.onStart(Evolutions.scala:459)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
  at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
  at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
  at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
  at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
  at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
  at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
  at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
  at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
```

Please notice that I run evolutions in Mode.Prod with evolutions.use.locks=true, otherwise database connection would be in auto-commit mode, which opposes making evolutions transactional.

Comment: But have you tried to run the SQL code manually outside of Play? Also evolutions.use.locks=true is not for auto commit, but for preventing race conditions in multi-node environments. So if you are running you app at one node, you could try to disable this parameter.

Comment: @cosmolev you're right about preventing race conditions, but if you look at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala you will see that the only place where autocommit is set to ```false``` is the ```withLock``` method.

Comment: @cosmolev Surely, I've tested the SQL code and it works correctly. It seems like the issue is somehow related to the recent fix to BoneCP: https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/commit/1213ea53a7490998ba6996d182333bec3e1522ea I use the 0.8.0.RELEASE, btw.